# unable to remove the empty spaces around image after using clip-path

Tags: css

I am unable to remove the empty spaces around this clipped image. The original size of the image is 1200x800 but I want to show only a small section of this image at a certain point on the page. But in the background it still takes the size of the entire image creating all the space between the header, image and the content. Here's my [Plunker code](https://plnkr.co/edit/T6F4mzXQunRgsxEALl4U?p=preview)

CSS

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    clip-path: inset(248px 0 238px 0);
}
```

HTML

```
  <body>
    <h1>Header Here</h1>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1200x800" alt="image" />
    <div>
      Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.....
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: That is simply not how a clip-path works. It decides what part of your image are _shown_, but it does not change the image dimensions. Parts outside of your path are not actually "cut off" the image _element_ inside your page.

Comment: I dont think so it is possible. Your image is occupying div space and you are displaying part of image.

Comment: aah.. so do I have to take two different images now or is there any other way in which I can get this functionality from the same image. What I need is a clipped part and the entire image on the same page.

Comment: As @CBroe said, `clip-path` is not intended for that, and also still does not have a great browser support. You are better off placing your `img` inside a new relatively positioned `div` with the dimensions you want to show and `overflow: hidden`. Then make your `img` inside absolutely positioned and play with the `left` and `top` properties to offset the image location to where you want it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code for your solution:

```css
    #img {
      position: relative;
      width: 800px;
      height: 100px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: -220px;
       left: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="img">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1200x800" alt="image" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by using the tool https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/.

I moved each of the points in the white space back 5%. This will give the clip-path mask more breathing room or bleed space.

[Giving the path less space gives the image more room.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MSgC.jpg)